# Subscribe is not a Function Angular / Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I'm writing a chat app and I'm using a Node server and socket.io server side and Angular and socket.io-client client side.  Unfortunately I get a "this.socketService.getMessage(...).subscribe is not a function" error when I run it.  Everything else seems to work.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'chat';
  registered = false;
  username: string;

  constructor(public socketService: SocketService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.socketService
      .getMessage()
      .subscribe(msg => {
        if (msg === 'Registered') {
          this.registered = true;
          console.log(this.registered)
        }
      });
  }

  register(username: string): void {
    console.log(username)
    this.username = username;
    this.socketService.sendMessage('register', username);
  }

  send(message: string): void {
    this.socketService.sendMessage('message', message);
  }


}
```

socket.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {

  socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.socket.on('message', msg => {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }

  sendMessage(type: string, words: any): void {
    console.log(type, words);
    this.socket.emit(type, words);
  }
}
```

Comment: `let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket = io(this.url);
      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);    
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };  
    })     ` do like this. Because socket.on is not observable. you need to convert it to observable.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda That worked.  Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

`this.socket.on` doesn't returns an Observable so you can't `.subscribe()` as you would do with an observable.

It returns a **Socket** as described into the docs : https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback