# Unsubscribe is not a function in Angular 16

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

This is the code in service

```
getMsg(users_data: any): Subscription {

return this.socket.on('loadNewChat', async (data: any) => {
    if(users_data.user1._id===data.sender_id && users_data.user2._id===data.reciever_id){
 

    const container = document.getElementById('chat-container');

    const element = document.createElement('ul');
    if (this.msg !== data.message) {
      element.innerHTML = data.message;
      element.style.textAlign = 'right';
      container!.appendChild(element);
    } 
  }
  });
}
```

This is how it is in component.ts

```
private getMsgSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dialogdata = this.data
    this.UserData.sender_id = this.dialogdata.user2._id
    this.UserData.reciever_id = this.dialogdata.user1._id
   this.getMsgSubscription = this.sockservice.getMsg(this.dialogdata)
    this.sockservice.getChats(this.UserData)

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.getMsgSubscription!== undefined) {
      this.getMsgSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

  }
```

I am doing this to prevent the where the function seems to be called again and again

[image]

But while doing so I get the error

```
chatview.component.ts:39  ERROR TypeError: this.getMsgSubscription.unsubscribe is not a function
    at ChatviewComponent.ngOnDestroy (chatview.component.ts:58:31)
    at executeOnDestroys (core.mjs:7359:32)
    at cleanUpView (core.mjs:7267:9)
    at destroyViewTree (core.mjs:7095:21)
    at destroyLView (core.mjs:7245:9)
    at RootViewRef.destroy (core.mjs:13738:9)
    at ComponentRef.destroy (core.mjs:14195:23)
    at DomPortalOutlet._disposeFn (portal.mjs:321:30)
    at DomPortalOutlet._invokeDisposeFn (portal.mjs:217:18)
    at DomPortalOutlet.detach (portal.mjs:201:14)
```

Why does this error happen? How to correct it?

Comment: I see no issues on your code can you try to unsunbscribe like this  ```ngOnDestroy(): void { this.getMsgSubscription?.unsubscribe(); }```

Comment: I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscribe is not a Function Angular / Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103913/subscribe-is-not-a-function-angular-socket-io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot unsubscribe from a subject.

You can either use this :

```js
this.getMsgSubscription.complete();
```

To close it, or when you subscribe, use

```js
this.getMsgSubscription.asObservable().subscribe().unsubscribe();
```

To convert it to an observable that you unsubscribe from.

Comment: Thanks I found this works along with a method I got from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription